# error robots txt no es valido pero no tengo ni uso robots txt google pagespeed

Tags: html

En mi hosting, desactive cache, tengo https, mi estructura html5 está bien como se ve en las imágenes, no uso robots txt ni me gusta prefiero que indexe mi web estatica, mi hosting en bug no marca error alguno, solo no aparezco en buscadores de google, ingreso a mi sitio web desde internet con la url y al inspeccionar no marca error

ayuda cómo resuelvo ese error, a lo mejor agregando la etiqueta w3 pero eso para qué [image: robotstxt no es valido]

Comment: crea un archivo `robots.txt` vacío. lo que puede estar sucediendo ahi es que tu página de 404 ( el script o rule que carga ese html cuando no se encuentra un archivo ) no esté enviando los headers adecuados. si el header fuera 404 ahi verías un "no se ha encontrado robots.txt" o mensaje parecido

Comment: Pues el mensaje de error está encontrando un archivo `robots.txt`, de hecho, te está diciendo cuáles son los errores de dicho archivo. Al parecer tienes un `robots.txt` con contenido HTML.

Comment: @aloMalbarez Si me funcionó tu método te felicito, gracias, mejoró todo, el SEO en google search console, no creí que me fueran a contestar

Comment: es importante que la página 404 envíe los headers correctos, mas allá de mostrar el error en bonito para los internautas, sino el resto de crawlers, browsers, proxies y un largo etcétera verán el header "200 found" e interpretaran el documento como encontrado. en el caso de `robots.txt` tiene un formato establecido así que si lo "encuentra" ( con un header 200 found, en vez de 404 not found ) y es un html da ese error. en cuanto a SEO, hints, configuración y otras certificaciones es importante que si no existe el archivo necesario/esperado el header sea 404.

Comment: 2/ ejemplos de archivos que si no existen se espera un 404 ver [`.well-known`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_URI#List_of_well-known_URIs)  el formato esperado puede ser texto, json, xml, etc.